# How can I combine binary a set of data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of values vertically

```
2,4
4,7
5,8
  9
```

I want to have binary combination of each two values in vertical for example 2 and 4, 2 and 5 etc . the same for the second

```
2 4
2 5
4 5
4 7
4 8 
 .
 .
 .
```

Ok it seems very complicated so I try to make it easier 
I convert my data into horizon

I have 
2,4,5
4,7,8,9

I want to have the binary combination of the first row

```
2 4
2 5
4 5
```

and the the binary combination of the second row

```
4 7
4 8
4 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

Comment: Were you meaning that under `5 8` you would want `5 9` and then under that would you have `9`? If can you can explain better why `2 5` appeared below `2 4`, that would be very helpful

Comment: @zedfoxus the first column is separated by a comma from the second column (I can convert it horizon) is it is easier. The first column combination binary and the second column combination binary

Comment: @zedfoxus is this clear now ?

Comment: It is not clear what data structure your numbers are contained within (or are they in a file?)

Comment: @jmd_dk they come from `R`I can save them in txt or pretty much any format

Comment: The answer to your question depends heavily upon how your data is represented *in Python*, so please read them into Python and store them in some data structure (two lists, a 2D Numpy array ,...) and rephrase your question accordingly.

Comment: @ jmd_dk can you please suggest me a solution based on a txt file? because I am very new in python and I don't know what I must do

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't understand what pattern you want to follow. Say I have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. What should the result be and why?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. Try this code:

**test.py**

```
#!/bin/python

# put items side by side
# take first item and put the next item besides it
# if there are any more items after the next, put that item besides the first item
# if there are no more items after the next, switch to the next item in the list
# repeat
def two_items_side_by_side(mylist):
    list_len = len(mylist)
    for i in range(list_len):
        for j in range(i+1, list_len):
            print '{} {}'.format(mylist[i], mylist[j])

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# these are two lists
list1 = [2, 4, 5]
list2 = [4, 7, 8, 9]

two_items_side_by_side(list1)
two_items_side_by_side(list2)
```

When you run this, your results will look like so:

**Result**

```
python test.py
2 4
2 5
4 5
4 7
4 8
4 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

If your test case is a string with each line containing comma separated text like this, you can use test2.py as an example

```
2,4
4,7
5,8
 ,9
```

**test2.py**

```
#!/bin/python

# put items side by side
# take first item and put the next item besides it
# if there are any more items after the next, put that item besides the first item
# if there are no more items after the next, switch to the next item in the list
# repeat
def two_items_side_by_side(mylist):
    list_len = len(mylist)
    for i in range(list_len):
        for j in range(i+1, list_len):
            print '{} {}'.format(mylist[i], mylist[j])

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# process the data and store them into a list
# then do the same work as we did in the first example
def convert_data_into_lists():
    lines = data.split('\n')
    for line in lines:
        # ignore empty lines
        if len(line.strip()) < 1:
            continue

        # split by comma and ignore if we don't get 2 or more values
        items = line.split(',')
        if len(items) < 2:
            continue

        # put first item in list1 and second item in list2
        if len(items[0].strip()) > 0: list1.append(items[0].strip())
        if len(items[1].strip()) > 0: list2.append(items[1].strip())

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# this is my string
data = """
2,4
4,7
5,8
 ,9
"""

list1 = []
list2 = []

convert_data_into_lists()
two_items_side_by_side(list1)
two_items_side_by_side(list2)
```

**Result**

```
python test2.py
2 4
2 5
4 5
4 7
4 8
4 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

There are more elegant ways to write this code. I have written it in a manner that will help you understand the code and try it out yourself.

## Requirement change

Based on the change in requirement, data is in a text file. We will take three test cases (see in results). To accommodate the requirements, I am going to use the same code I used in `test2.py`. Instead of creating individual lists for each column we have in our text file, I will create one list that will dynamically contain as many lists as you have columns in your text file.

**Code**

```
#!/bin/python

# put items side by side
# take first item and put the next item besides it
# if there are any more items after the next, put that item besides the first item
# if there are no more items after the next, switch to the next item in the list
# repeat
def two_items_side_by_side(mylist):
    list_len = len(mylist)
    for i in range(list_len):
    for j in range(i+1, list_len):
        print '{} {}'.format(mylist[i], mylist[j])

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# process the data and store them into a list
# then do the same work as we did in the first example
def convert_data_into_lists():

    with open(data) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        # ignore empty lines
        if len(line.strip()) < 1:
            continue

        # split by comma and ignore if we don't get 2 or more values
        items = line.split(',')

        counter = 0
        for item in items:

            if len(mylist) < counter + 1:
                mylist.append([])
            if len(item.strip()) > 0:
                mylist[counter].append(item.strip())
            counter += 1

# -------------------------------------------------------------------

# this is my string
data = 'test.txt'

mylist = []

convert_data_into_lists()
for individual_list in mylist:
    two_items_side_by_side(individual_list)
```

**Result**

**Case 1**

```
Data:
2,4
4,7
5,8
 ,9

Results:
2 4
2 5
4 5
4 7
4 8
4 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

**Case 2**

```
Data:
2,4
4,7
5,8
6,9

Results:
2 4
2 5
2 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

**Case 3**

```
Data:
2,4,10
4,7,11
5,8,
 ,9,13

Results:
2 4
2 5
2 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
4 7
4 8
4 9
7 8
7 9
8 9
10 11
10 13
11 13
```

Comment: people vote negative to my question so I cannot like your answer yet. Once question If my data is txt. How can I get it to list? also imagine I have more than 2 lists. It is a txt file. Thank you

Comment: I have included an example program that uses a test file called test.txt in the same directory as test.py. The text file can have as many columns separated by comma as you like. The only requirement is that each line should have equal number of commas. Notice the results.

Comment: Also, note that different people react differently to your question. I don't know who downvoted your question. Don't take it personally. Review the recommendations provided to you and improve your question continually. Because people don't like your question does not mean you cannot like anyone's answer or comment. People are trying to help you at the expense of their own time. I urge you to be a part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have values stores in two collectables, use list comprehension

```
from itertools import izip_longest
a = [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,None)]
b,c = izip_longest(*a)
d = [(i, j) for i in b if i  for j in c if j]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the original problem. The OP wanted to give all possible binary combinations from a single list, rather than give the possible combinations from merging two lists.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

By modifying the code above to only use a single parameter, we can read the contents of a csv file and (using some form of delimiter) provide combinations across the entire data set. Just call total_zipper() and replace 'filename.txt' with your file name.

```
def total_zipper():

    def zipper(a):
        lst = []
        for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
            lst+=zip(a,a[i:])
        return sorted(lst)

    f = open('filename.txt','r')
    return [zipper(line) for line in f]
```

This treats all lines as iterables (Strings). For readline() to work, I believe you need a return statement at the end of each line in the txt. See the [input/output page for Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html.) for more.

---

Here's the shortest version I could come up with. You can use the built-in `zip()` function. This, when combined with list slicing, results in a pythonic way to pair the values in the required order.

```
def zipper(a,b):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1,len(b)+1):
        lst+=zip(a,b[i:])
    return sorted(lst)
```

Now simply call zipper on the various rows of data.

```
>>> a = [2,4,5]
>>> b = [4,7,8,9]
>>> print(zipper(a,a))
[(2, 4), (2, 5), (4, 5)]
>>> print(zipper(b,b))
[(4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 9)]
```

---

As a side note, I tried to use list comprehension to make the code shorter. For example, the following code *does the same thing as zipper(a)*:

```
def zipper(a):
    return list(zip(a,a[i:]) for i in range(1,len(a)+1))
```

However, with zip() returning generator objects in Python 3, the results aren't as "clean" as the output from the version above. I'd have to use `next()` on each generator object in the list outputted by zipper in order to get the same output, but this is a tedious process. Anyone have suggestions for making the list comprehension work?

Comment: it seems cool but my list is together and not list1, list2. I have a txt file which all those lists are in there

Comment: Do you mean that the solution above would suffice if it was combined with a scanner/reader for '[' and ']' characters?

Comment: Actually, the solution above only needs one of the two parameters. (You'd need to call zipper(a) rather than zipper(a,a) since the multiple row combination is not necessary.) As such we can just read in the file and use a for-loop over all the rows. See my edit.